# Allow only numbers and one single (+) sing on an tel input filed

Tags: javascript, html, jquery

I have a tel input filed where I want to allow the user to put only numbers start with a single (+) sign. Telephone number will be like: +447574123456.
My code is like below code, where I was able to put more than one plus sign.
but I want only one plus sign on this field

```
<input type="tel" class="telInput" id="phone" name="phone" value="">

$(document).on("input", "#phone", function (e) {
    this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9+]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
    $(this).attr({"minlength": "10","maxlength": "15"}); 
});
```

anyone with help is appreciated. thanks in advance.

Comment: why not add the **+** yourself and ask the user for just numbers?

Comment: I have already add + on the code, you did not understand what my need, kindly read the title and description

Comment: As a user, I would be very annoyed to enter myself the + sign, if it's mandatory

Answer (score 0):

You can try with that.

But the best and fastest is to add the "+" yourself and just ask for the number as stipulated by @Ahsan Khan

You will also need to check if the number begins with "+"

```js
$(document).on("input", "#phone", function (e) {
  this.value = this.value.replace(/[^0-9+]/g, '').replace(/(\..*)\./g, '$1');
  $(this).attr({"minlength": "10","maxlength": "15"}); 
});

$('#phone').on('keyup keydown',function(){
  checkPhone(this);
});

function checkPhone(elem){
  if( $('#phone').val() != '' && $(elem).val().match(/\+/g) != null){
    if( $(elem).val().match(/\+/g).length > 1 ){
      var value = $('#phone').val();
      $(elem).val(value.slice(0,-1));
    }
  }

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<input type="tel" class="telInput" id="phone" name="phone" value="">
```